# Feh and i3-gaps not playing nicely

Tags: ubuntu, i3, feh

so I'm using `exec_always feh --bg-scale *wallpaper*` and it sets it correctly. I'm also using `i3-gaps` which can be found [here](https://github.com/Airblader/i3). When I start setting my windows up, my wallpaper starts freaking out. I'm not quite sure if this is feh or i3-gaps. Basically where ever I create a new window, more of my wallpaper turns black. Can be seen here:[image]

Comment: The i3-gaps docs mention that you need to disable window title bars, did you try that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a wallpaper is set with `feh` using any command

```
feh --bg-*
```

a file is created in your `$HOME`-dir, named `.fehbg`, which basically stores the latest `feh` command that you ran. Thus, the file content would be similar to

```
#!/bin/sh
feh --bg-scale '/home/username/Pictures/mywallpaper.jpg'
```

This script can then be run from your i3config file, by adding the line

```
exec --no-startup-id exec bash $HOME/.fehbg
```

If you run `i3` with gaps, I would recommend including these two lines in your config as well:

```
for_window [class=".*"] border pixel 0
hide_edge_borders both
```

This disables all borders, which is mentioned to prevent issues with gaps in i3-gaps.

Comment: As this was quite some time ago, I did figure it out that it was infact the borders. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using

```
exec_always --no-startup-id feh --no-fehbg --bg-scale ~/.wallpapers/black.jpg &
```

to set my wallpaper on [i3](https://github.com/i3/i3) although I'm not using `i3-gaps`. If the above command doesn't fix your issue on `i3-gaps`, try installing `i3` and use the same command to verify whether that fixes your issue. If yes, then it's probably a bug in `i3-gaps` and you should open an issue [here](https://github.com/Airblader/i3/issues). If it doesn't, I suspect that it's an issue with your graphics drivers. Which graphic card are you using? Which drivers have you installed? Which GNU/Linux distribution are you using? What is the output of `uname -r`? Did you disable the titlebars on `i3-gaps` as suggested [here](https://github.com/Airblader/i3/wiki/FAQ) and like [Wieland](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4699/wieland) mentioned in the comments?

Comment: this worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: I3 gaps with wallpaper]

You mean like this?

Just install `compton` and run it in the config file: `exec compton`

This way, you wont have to disable your window's border. (personally I don't want to that neither)